# How to Call loggedin username in Django url

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I have djando login url, after user loggedin, its getting called as bellow:

```
(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url= '/home/')),
```

I want to pass loggedin username in above url , such as

```
(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url= '<username>')),
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend deriving the `RedirectView` class in a view, like this:

```
class HomeRedirectView(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'home'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "/user/{}/".format(self.request.user)
```

In `urls.py`:

```
(r'^$', HomeRedirectView.as_view()),
```

Comment: arocks, sorry for late reply, can you please tell me where do i write HomeRedirectView class in view file? Means as RedirectView defination am importing in my urls file as "from django.views.generic import RedirectView" and i dont want to edit the django's default defination of RedirectView, i just want to override it , So, am bit confused that where should i write this HomeRedirectView class so that i could called when user loggedin.

Comment: You could put this class anywhere, typically in the `views.py` of an app. Then import it in your urls file as `from myapp.views import HomeRedirectView`

Comment: But arocks, it goes to that url after logged in , but now i want that after logged out it should again go to home url such as /home/

Comment: You are probably looking for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Comment: Currently after i logged out, when i revisite the site          " http://127.0.0.1:8000/AnonymousUser/ "  this url is getting called according to url and views wriiten above.I want it to be as " http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ ".  Please Suggest

Comment: I have gone through the logic of redirecting url as we did above and i found that we are overriding the default defination provided by django for RedirectView, hence we are not getting the proper value in url when user is logged out. So can you suggest on this issue. what shoul i do to make that url as " 127.0.0.1:8000/home "