# How to Call default home url in django when i logged out

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-urls

Please visit this link for getting whole idea behind this question

[How to Call loggedin username in Django url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826929/how-to-call-loggedin-username-in-django-url)

Here i have discussed my points in this link but i didnt got specific answer for my issue that , when user loggedin i wanted it to be displayed in my url as 
" 127.0.0.1:8000/username " as i got the solution in above link as create user defind HomeRedirectView which calls initially when user logsin. and it works successfully, but i got an issue when i logged out and revisit the url as " 127.0.0.1:8000/ " then this url automatically becomes " 127.0.0.1:8000/AnonymousUser " and am getting the error as "NoReverseMatch", for that i have to specifically write it into url as " 127.0.0.1:8000/home/ " then it works. So can any one suggest me how to make url as " 127.0.0.1:8000/home/ ". To know about what i have done uptill now ,please visit above link and you will come to know from the discussion.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you got there is not the right solution, the right solution is to use the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting and point it to a view function, a named URL pattern or a direct URL.

Once a user is logged in using the default authentication mechanism of django, the request will automatically be redirected to this page.

Your second problem is when you logout a user, you want to be redirected to a specific URL. If you use the correct solution above, then all you need to do is:

1. Set [`LOGOUT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#logout-url) in your `settings.py`.
2. Create your logout view, it can be as simple as [this example from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out):

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import redirect
   from django.contrib.auth import logout


   def logout_view(request):
       logout(request)
       return redirect('/home/')
   ```

If you want to stick with your original solution, then modify it like this:

```
class HomeRedirectView(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'home'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return "/user/{}/".format(self.request.user)
        else:
            return '/home/'
```

Comment: Thanx for your solution Burhan..Its worked... According to your second option given , i tried n it works successfully...Thats great . Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things a little, the following will allow you to redirect to a user home page if a user is logged in, or it will display an un-logged in view. I have made the assumption that the username in the URL is purely for display purposes (otherwise it could be a security issue for your application.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
   url(r'^/$', 'home', name='home'),
   url(r'^user/[-_.\w\d]+/$', 'user_home', name='user-home'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404


def home(request):
    """
    Home page
    """
    # If a user is authenticated then redirect them to the user page
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('user-home', request.user.username)
    else:
        return render(request, "myapp/home.html")

@login_required
def user_home(request):
    """
    User specific home page, assume the username in URL is just for decoration.
    """
    return render(request, "mpapp/home_user.html", {
        "user": request.user
    }
```

Comment: Its also a good idea Tim, but i hav many modules which are linked with this User defined class, so i got solution from Burhan, n it works. Thanx for your suggession also.